# How to pass data from one action to another in oozie workflow

Tags: oozie

In action "A1" I am adding two numbers 10 & 20 so the result will be 30. Now this result 30 should be given as input to next action "A2". How to do this ?

```
<workflow-app name="JavaFlow1" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
<start to="A1"/>
<action name="A1">
    <java>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <main-class>com.demo.Test1</main-class>
        <arg>10</arg>
        <arg>20</arg>
        <capture-output/>
    </java>
    <ok to="A2"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
</action>
<action name="A2">
    <java>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <main-class>com.demo.Test2</main-class>
        <arg>100</arg>
        <capture-output/>
    </java>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
</action>
<kill name="kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```

Comment: This is what you need to do. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41381691/2254048 Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one check completion status of LoadApplicationService?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381464/how-does-one-check-completion-status-of-loadapplicationservice)